# Python generate JSON from two dictionaries

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have two dictionaries in python 3, called a and b which when dumped as JSON come out as below:

```
a = {"person": 26.94, "car": 99.49, "dog": 50.56}

b = {"filename": "1234.jpg", "model": "model1", "prototxt": "prototxt.txt"}
```

I need to combine these into the JSON format below but I am a bit lost on the approach in python, so welcome any pointers!

```
{
"payload": {
    "config": [{
        "model": "model1",
        "filename": "1234.jpg",
        "prototxt": "prototxt.txt"
    }],
    "results": [{
            "object": "person",
            "value": 26.94
        },
        {
            "object": "car",
            "value": 99.49
        },
        {
            "object": "dog",
            "value": 50.56
        }
    ]
 }
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Why do you have `"value": 99.98` against `"object": "person"`? Shouldn't it be `26.94`?

Comment: Hi Rogan, Apologies - typo, which I changed. I'm struggling to generate the JSON at all. I generate the data into the dictionaries in a for loop when iterating over a model, but have hit a hard stop trying to understand how to go from there to the above JSON format.  The above format I wrote as it's compatible with a downstream API we're using (into apache nifi).

Comment: `{'payload': {'config':[b], 'results':[{'object':k, 'value':v} for k, v in a.items()]}}`

Comment: You're going to need to apply a transformation for `a` to convert it into `results` format, put it in a nested dictionary that matches the structure you want. (do what Steven Rumbalski suggests) Then just dump it with `json.dumps()` (use the `json` module)

Comment: Guys thanks so much for the tips - I'm going to have a shot at this now.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by the following code:

```
a = {"person": 26.94, "car": 99.49, "dog": 50.56}
b = {"filename": "1234.jpg", "model": "model1", "prototxt": "prototxt.txt"}
a_list= []
for record in a:
    a_list.append({'object':record, 'value':a[record]})

payload = {'config':[b], 'results':a_list}
data = {"payload":payload}

# You can print this in the terminal/notebook with
print json.dumps(data, indent=4)

# Or save with
json_string = json.dumps(data)
with open('/path/to/file/payload.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

It's a matter of making entries in dictionaries and packaging them up in strings to add into new higher dictionaries.

Comment: `json` is part of the standard library so there is no need to use `pip`. In any case, this seems to be exactly what they are looking for.

Comment: Nice. You can also do this in a single nested mixed list/dict comprehension: `{"payload": {"config": [b], "results": [{"object": k, "value": v} for k, v in a.items()]}}`

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys, exactly what I was looking for. Problem solved!